# Completion with help

Tags: completion, help

I'm using `completing-read` to get an argument for an interactive command.  The argument is a non-intuitive word (required for my application), so the completion list looks like this:

```
Possible completions are:
faz   foo   bar   baz
```

I'd like it to also show some help, something like this:

```
Possible completions are:
faz   Pogo quote part 2
foo   Regular fubar
bar   All the soap
baz   Pogo quote part 1
```

Is there a straight-forward way to accomplish this, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "straight-forward", but you can do it as follows:

```
(let* ((comps '(("faz" "Pogo quote part 2")
                ("foo" "Regular fubar")
                ...))
       (completion-extra-properties
        `(:annotation-function
          ,(lambda (s) (format "  %s" (cadr (assoc s comps)))))))
  (completing-read "Prompt: " comps))
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!